# MySQL select from multiple tables that have different columns number

Tags: mysql, select

I'm new to MySQL so I really need some help with an issue I'm facing:
I have **7** tables in same database with some datas from tests:
The 7 tables have different columns but they all have these columns:

> - `name`.
> - `second_name`.
> - `status`.

In `status` are added current status of each student (accepted or rejected) and I want to display using select the `name`, `second_name` *from the 7 tables* `where status = accepted`.

I managed to display from 1 table

```
SELECT name, second_name FROM test1 WHERE status="accepted";
```

But I can not figure out how to display from all 7.
It will be a real help for me if somebody could give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind duplicate student names with multiple accepted tests, you can try doing it with `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT name, second_name FROM test1 WHERE status='accepted')
UNION ALL
(SELECT name, second_name FROM test2 WHERE status='accepted')
UNION ALL
(SELECT name, second_name FROM test3 WHERE status='accepted')
-- ...and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's better to normalize database to have all the names, secondnames and statuses in the separate table and do the only select instead of UNION to improve performace.